# Freezing Bananas With Less Waste

Tags: waste, storage, food-storage

My wife likes to freeze bananas by removing their skin, wrapping them in aluminum foil, and placing them in the freezer.  She eats a couple of bananas per day.  So, this is using up a lot of aluminum foil.  She tries to reuse the foil as much as possible.  But, they get easily ripped after a couple of uses and we have to waste water washing them.  Is there a way to freeze bananas that isn't so wasteful?  For her to try it out, it will have to produce the same effect as using foil.

Comment: *" For her to try it out, it will have to produce the same effect as using foil."*   What are the "effects" that she is currently getting by using foil to wrap them in individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I freeze bananas in a plastic container, which I wash and reuse. I also wash and reuse Ziploc-type plastic bags, which work equally well, but don't last quite as long.

If your wife prefers aluminium, you can probably find an aluminium container (e.g. in an outdoor store), which should last you for several decades.

Answer (score 7):

I simply freeze them, they don't need a container if you're going to eat them soonish (within a month, perhaps).

When you take one out if you run it under water for a few seconds the skin loosens up and they just pop out.  I squeeze them into my smoothies.

If your wife eats them as a whole fruit, rather than in a smoothie, you can improve the condition a bit by putting them inside a slightly insulated container so they freeze more slowly.  If you can slow down the speed of freezing they will crystallize less, making them seem a bit fresher when they thaw (the crystallization harms the cells and makes them mushy).

Answer (score 6):

Like other fruits and vegetables I would just put them into a plastic container. It is practical to separate the pieces by plastic foil so that they can be easily separated in the frozen state.

Both the boxes and foils can be reused without washing for a limited time when kept in cold. Later they can be washed and reused again.

Answer (score 5):

We just freeze bananas in their skins. But I do that when they're getting a bit old, and when I thaw them it's for cooking, so I'm not sure how edible they are.

Answer (score 4):

I would chop them into suitable chunks and pop into a freezer bag, making sure the bags are not over filled and freeze only a few bags at a time on a clear bit of freezer shelf.

Once frozen then can be stacked as normal in your freezer. Now I can grab the quantity I need.